Frobenius complement by Frobenius kernel
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind.
I first recall the necessary definitions. It is given a group G.

A Frobenius complement of G is a subgroup of G which is proper, non-trivial, self-normalising and which has trivial intersection with its conjugates different than itself. If a group admits a Frobenius complement, it is said to be Frobenius.
Given a subgroup H of G, a Frobenius kernel of H in G is a normal proper subgroup of G which is such that NH = G and has trivial intersection with H.

By Frobenius' theorem, every Frobenius complement admits a Frobenius kernel. My question is if the vice-versa is true, i.e., if a subgroup H of G admits a Frobenius kernel, is H a Frobenius complement?

No. Your definition of Frobenius kernel is just a normal complement, which can exist in many non-Frobenius cases. For example $G=C_2\times C_2$, $H$ is one of the $C_2$, and $K$ the other.
